# UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, activity-lifecycle

I am getting a random crash "lateinit property binding has not been initialized". Most of the time it's working fine but a few time randomly we are getting this crash on crashlytics.

Please let me know what's wrong here

I have a BaseActivity with following code

```
abstract class BaseActivity<D : ViewDataBinding> : AppComptActivity() {
    abstract val layoutId: Int
    lateinit val binding: D
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutId)
        ....

    }
}
```

I have a HomeActivity which override BaseActivity with following code

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityHomeBinding>() {

    override val layoutId: Int get() = R.layout.activity_home

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle)
        ....

    }
}
```

I am using bottomNavigation menu and one of the fragment is HomeFragment

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmenntHomeBinding>() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState:Bundle)
        (activity as HomeActivity).binding.appBarHome.visible(false)
        //HERE I AM GETTING  lateinit property binding has not been initialized crash
    }
}
```

I don't want to use isInitialized property of lateinit as this will not solve my issue

Comment: My guess is, without seeing other parts of your code, that the code is trying to access it in the incorrect state (basically fragment's onViewCreated gets triggered before the actual binding variable is being set. How do you put the fragment to the activity? Using navigation component or fragment container?

Comment: Using navigation component. and most of the time it's working fine. After pushing it in Production only these issues are coming for  some users

Comment: Hmmm then maybe proguard? But in any case, handling it like this can be dangerous, I'd suggest hooking to destination change in HomeActivity and based on the direction, hide/show the `appBarHome`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, I'd suggest instead of calling parent container (Activity) objects directly, register a listener to a navigation change like this in HomeActivity:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    if(destination.id = R.id.homeFragment) {
        // TODO hide/show your view here
    }
}
```

In that case, you are sure that the view gets hidden/shown when it should be without relying on the HomeFragment being only in HomeActivity as this can change in the future and your app will start crashing

Comment: I am moving the code to addOnDestinationChangedListener in HomeActivity, let's see if we get the issue gets fixed or not in Production

Answer (score 1):

If you have an orientation change or other config change, or the OS process is killed while in the background and the user returns to the app, Android will recreate the `Activity` and the `Fragment`s.

Unfortunately, it creates the `Fragment`s first, before creating the `Activity`. So you cannot rely on the existence of the `Activity` until the `Fragment` has been attached to the `Activity`. You should move code that relies on the existence of the `Activity` to
`onActivityCreated()`.

---

Note: I also agree with the comment about not doing it this way. Your `Fragment` should not make assumptions like this (that it is hosted by `HomeActivity`), but instead should make some callback to the hosting `Activity` and let the hosting `Activity` set the visibility of the app bar (or whatever else it wants to do).

Comment: I think this is happening because of OS process is killed because I don't have any configuration change in the App. The onActivityCreated is deprecated hence I have use onViewCreated for making the changes. I am moving the code to addOnDestinationChangedListener in HomeActivity, let see if we get the issue gets fixed or not in Production

Comment: Do you know any why to create OS process kill scenario ?

Comment: What happens when you just rotate the screen to change the orientation from portrait to landscape? In this case your `Activity` will get killed and recreated by Android.

Comment: OS process kill scenario? Low memory (other apps need memory) or your app is in the background for more than about 30 minutes. Android will probably kill it off then,.

Comment: When `onViewCreated()` is called, the `Activity` still may not exist. This is too early.